# Why was my question migrated from Stack Overflow to Web Masters

Tags: support, migration

I have my Stack Overflow account and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22660/how-do-i-set-starting-at-12-value-for-a-grouped-product-in-magento) question was migrated to Pro webmasters

Why was this question migrated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a little surprised there isn't an FAQ question about this. (Maybe this could be it?) A question is migrated when it is off topic for Stack Overflow, but is on topic for the destination site.

In this case, your question was migrated because it was not about programming specifically, but was about higher-level tasks involved in managing a website.

Comment: This question is asked all the time, but usually people want a specific answer for their question, not "because it's off-topic on the source site and on-topic on the destination site"

Answer (score 1):

Because there are a wealth of people on that site who know about Magento - and, best I can tell, your question wasn't programming-related - and fits within the scope of the other site more aptly.

Answer (score 1):

As the migrator in question, I'll second what David has said.  It was not programming related, and therefore off topic for StackOverflow.

There is not much traffic for managing Magento website configurations on Webmasters, unfortunately for you, but it is on topic there.

Perhaps you should check out this [Magento proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25439/magento) at Area 51?